# How to load a React Component in an existing jQuery application on jQuery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-redux

I have an existing single page application build in jQuery/HTML. I can't rewrite the existing application in React because it's very big.

I am planning to build new screens in that existing application with React. However I wonder, how can render React screens on click of a button/link from existing navigation?

It's something like, the click handler function is a normal JavaScript which is outside the React component and inside a handler function I have to write code to load new screen which is made in React Component.

I am not directly including react.js and react-dom.js in index.html, rather i am creating a bundle.js by using babel and webpack. So accessing ReactDOM.render outside bundle.js is throwing error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With React, you use [ReactDOM.render](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) to attach layout created with React component to the DOM.

It does not really matter to which DOM node to attach, or when you call that function. The usual way is to do it on page load, but you can do it when a button is clicked just as well.

It could look something like this:

```
$('#my-button').click(() => ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, $('#my-container')[0]);
```

In this example, `<MyApp />` would the root component of your React layout, and `my-container` would be some div on the page where you want to put the React layout.

#### What if I'm not using a module bundler?

If your existing page does not use any module bundler like webpack, you cannot easily import *ReactDOM* or use JSX notation in your plain jQuery code.

In this case, set up a webpack build to create the React layout and expose a global function that adds the React layout to the DOM. A beginner-friendly way to do this is using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

CRA can create a bundle that includes your JSX code and all the libraries you need. You include it in your page with a script tag, just like you include the jQuery library.

In your React app, create a global function that adds the React layout to the DOM, for example:

```
window.renderMyReactApp = element => ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, element);
```

In the jQuery code on your HTML page, call the function like so:

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
  window.renderMyReactApp($('#my-container')[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am sorry that i forgot to mention that i am not including react.js or react-dom.js directly in html. rather i am creating a bundle using babel and webpack. So accessing ReactDOM.render outside bundle.js is throwing error. Please suggest your idea.

Comment: Do you use webpack or some other bundler to bundle up your existing jQuery code?

Comment: No, I don't even bundle my existing jQuery code.. it's like loading each html on click with respective js and css included in that html. I know it's very old architecture but i can't change the existing app as it's huge.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer, it's great! I got some idea from your answer.